# Can I use redux-saga's es6 generators as onmessage listener for websockets or eventsource?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, redux-saga

I'm trying to get redux-saga working with the `onmessage` listener. I don't know why what I have isn't working.

I have the following set-up.

```
// sagas.js
import { take, put } from 'redux-saga';
import {transactions} from "./actions";

function* foo (txs) {
    console.log("yielding");  // appears in console
    yield put(transactions(txs));  // action *is not* dispatched
    console.log("yielded"); //appears in console
}

const onMessage = (event) => {
  const txs = JSON.parse(event.data);
  const iter = foo(txs);
  iter.next(); // do I really need to do this? 
};

function* getTransactions() {
  while(yield take('APP_LOADED')) {
    const stream = new EventSource(eventSourceUrl);

    stream.onopen = onOpen;
    stream.onmessage = onMessage;
    stream.onerror = onError;

    // this is just testing that `yield put` works 
    yield put(transactions([{baz : 42}])); //this action *is* dispatched
  }
};
```

When the `APP_LOADED` action is dispatched `getTransactions` is called, the stream is opened and the onMessage listener is called as data is received from the server, but I'm not having any luck in dispatching the action when calling `yield put(transactions(txs))` in the generator `foo`.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A Saga can be invoked only from inside another Saga (using `yield foo()` or `yield call(foo)`) .

In your example, the `foo` Saga is called from inside a normal function (`onMessage` callback) so it'll just return the iterator object. By yielding an iterator (or a call to a generator) from a Saga, we allow the redux-saga middleware to *intercept* that call and **run** the iterator in order to resolve all yielded Effects. But in your code, `stream.onmessage = onMessage` just do a simple assignement so the middleware won't notice anything.

As for the main question. Sagas typically takes events from the Redux store. You can use `runSaga` to connect a saga to a custom input/output source but it wont be trivial to apply that to the above use case. So I'll propose another alternative using simply the `call` effect. However, in order to introduce it, we'll have to shift from the **push** perspective of Events, to a **pull** perspective.

The traditional way to handle events is to register some event listener on some event source. Like assigning the `onMessage` callback to `stream.onmessage` in the example above. Each Event occurrence is *pushed* to the listener callback. The event source is in total control.

redux-saga adopts a different model: Sagas *pull* the desired Event. As callbacks, they typically do some processing. But they have total control on what to do next: they may chose to pull the same event again -which mimics the callback model- but they are not forced to. They may chose to pull another Event, start another Saga to take the relay or even terminate their execution. i.e. they are in control of their own logic of progression. All the event source can do is to resolve the queries for future events.

To integrate external push sources, we'll need to transpose the Event Source from the push model into the pull model; i.e. we'll have to build an *event iterator* from which we can pull the future events from the event source

Here is an example of deriving an `onmessage` iterator from an `EventSource`

```js
function createSource(url) {

  const source = new EventSource(url)
  let deferred

  source.onmessage = event => {
    if(deferred) {
      deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(event.data))
      deferred = null 
    }
  }

  return {
    nextMessage() {
      if(!deferred) {
        deferred = {}
        deferred.promise = 
          new Promise(resolve => deferred.resolve = resolve)
      }
      return deferred.promise
    }
  }
}
```

The above function returns an object with a `nextMessage` method that we can use to pull the future messages. Calling it will return a Promise that will resolve with the next incoming message.

Having the `createSource` API function. We can now use it by a simple `call` effect

```js
function* watchMessages(msgSource) {
  let txs = yield call(msgSource.nextMessage)
  while(txs) {
    yield put(transactions(txs))
    txs = yield call(msgSource.nextMessage)
  } 
}


function* getTransactionsOnLoad() {
  yield take('APP_LOADED')
  const msgSource = yield call(createSource, '/myurl')
  yield fork(watchMessages, msgSource)
}
```

You can find a [live running demo](https://jsbin.com/wumuri/edit?js,console) of the above code.

An advantage of the above approach is that it keeps the code inside Sagas fully declarative (using only declarative forms `fork` and `call`)

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer, there's a lot to digest! (Thanks also for redux-saga itself;) )

Comment: Is it guaranteed that each `nextMessage` is called before `source.onmessage` i.e is there any risk of messages being received by `onmessage` when `deferred` is `null`? And if there is no risk, is that just because of the way JavaScript's event loop works?

Comment: If my previous comment is true, can `createSource` be simplified to               `function createSource(url) {
  const source = new EventSource(url)
  const deferred = {}

  source.onmessage = event => deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(event.data))

  return {
    nextMessage : () => new Promise(resolve => deferred.resolve = resolve)
  }
}
`

Comment: @user5325596 Yes, `onmessage` callbacks will be scheduled in a new event queue. No message will be missed.

Comment: @user5325596 your simplified code will work as long as it's only used by **one saga**; and that saga will always wait for the next message before querieng the next message. Otherwise, successive `nextMessage` calls will keep overwriting the deferred. So only the last deferred will be resolved

Comment: @YassineElouafi could your watchMessages be rewritten as 
`
function* watchMessages(msgSource) {
  while(let txs = yield call(msgSource.nextMessage)) {
    yield put(transactions(msg))
  } 
}
`
And when would it end?

Comment: @YassineElouafi there is one `msg` that should be a `txs` in the second code block. Since it is 3 letters only I cannot edit. It caused me some confusion though.

Comment: @Jasper fixed. Thanks

Comment: The live demo was not working because of API changes. Here is an [updated version](https://jsbin.com/hapewakupu/edit?js,console).