# Redux saga: how to put a `yield put()` inside an event listener?

Tags: react-native, asynchronous, redux-saga, asynchronous-javascript, react-native-onesignal

I'm using `Redux saga` and `OneSignal` in my React Native app. In my saga I have the following generator function:

```
function* getOneSignalIDs() {
    try {
        OneSignal.init(appID)
        OneSignal.addEventListener('ids', (device) => {
            yield put(OneSignalActionCreators.getOneSignalIDsSuccess(device.pushToken, device.userId));
        });
    } catch(error) {}
}
```

The problem with this code is that `yield put` has to be inside a generator function, but my event listener isn't a generator.

Does anyone know how I can approach this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to tie emitted events events into redux-saga?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35277682/how-to-tie-emitted-events-events-into-redux-saga)

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: Thanks @ArchNoob this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38762340/3385744 from the post solve my issue